# Modern Alternatives for the Common Public Attribution License

Tags: license-recommendation, license-notice, relicensing, license

I am looking for a modern alternative or similar license to the Common Public Attribution License.

Here are some of the specific license attributions that I am looking for:

- A requirement that the Original Developer is attributed in distributions
- Network use is counted as distribution.
- Express grant of patent claims
- Trademarks and tradenames included are still exclusive property of the original developer and can only be used within permission of the owners.
- The code can be modified and used freely under those terms

Comment: What is the reason you are looking for a different license than CPAL? What is the problem with the CPAL in your opinion?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me as if you want [AGPLv3](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0.html).

> A requirement that the Original Developer is attributed in distributions

AGPLv3 s4 provides that *"You may convey verbatim copies of the Program's source code as you receive it, in any medium, provided that you conspicuously and appropriately publish on each copy an appropriate copyright notice*", so the original developer's (and subsequent contributors') copyright notices must be conspicuously maintained.

> Network use is counted as distribution.

AGPLv3 s13.

> Express grant of patent claims

AGPLv3 s11.

> Trademarks and tradenames included are still exclusive property of the original developer and can only be used within permission of the owners.

AGPLv3 s7e permits this.

> The code can be modified and used freely under those terms

AGPLv3 ss 2,4,5, and 6.

Comment: I am not sure the AGPL meets the attribution expectations. The CPAL attribution requirements are closer to clause 3 of the 4-clause BSD than attribution through copyright notices.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau I agree.  The OP's requirement in that regard, however, was merely that "*that the Original Developer is attributed in distributions*".  If the OP had been more specific about the nature and complexity of his/her attribution requirement, that might - as you say - have affected my answer.